# Struggling with Unavailable Requirements: Should I Hide Service Links or Opt for Empty State Pages?

Tags: hyperlinks, cta, tab, empty

I'm currently dealing with numerous instances where pages display requirements that users may not meet. For instance, a service that prints the latest card transactions, but the user doesn't have any cards during their visit.

Considering the scale and variety of services, creating specific call-to-action button for each one is not feasible. I'm contemplating a global solution. One option is to hide the link leading to a service if the required flow is not achievable. However, I'm concerned about potentially limiting visibility and awareness of the service. On the other hand, having a regular empty state page is an option, but I want to be mindful of not wasting the user's time.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if you can identify user groups and then have permissions / access controls to those user groups, it will help you limit the count from considering for all users to considering for a groups.

For example, I have 50 users. I identify them into two groups, A and B, three if you consider admin as a user group. Then I can decide what sections are accessible to these groups. That way you can hide the sections which are not necessary for those users. But I agree to your reasoning, that you need to show the sections that they can avail services, there you can show empty state with a CTA.

In short, both your options makes sense and you will need to do both of them, it will get easier if you create user groups and map them with permissions and access controls. Dong this can also help you in the long run.